# MapStruct Retrieving from arrayList

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm trying to use MapStruct to map two objects. I have been searching for a while and I haven't been able to find anything, though I'm new to programming so I'm sure it's easier than I'm making it.

Here is some stripped back code (Note that the real code is more complex, with the child object from the arraylist not being the same type as the destination objects child variable as it is here):

*SourceObject*

```
public class SourceObject {
    public ArrayList<ListObject> list = new ArrayList<ListObject>();

    public SourceObject() {
        list.add(new ListObject());
    }
}
```

*ListObject*

```
public class ListObject {
    public DetailsObject details = new DetailsObject();

    public ListObject() {
        details.forename="SourceForename";
        details.surname="SourceSurname";
    }
}
```

*DestinationObject*

```
public class DestinationObject {
    public DetailsObject details = new DetailsObject();

    public DestinationObject() {
        details.forename="DestinationForename";
        details.surname="DestinationSurname";
    }
}
```

*DetailsObject*

```
public class DetailsObject {
    public String forename;
    public String surname;
}
```

*Mapper*

```
@Mappings({
    @Mapping(target="details.forename", source="list.get(0).details.forename"),
    @Mapping(target="details.surname", source="list.get(0).details.surname"),
})
DestinationObject toDestination(SourceObject source);
```

This will work fine if I put DetailsObject directly inside SourceObject, but becomes a problem when I try to take it from the list. The error I get is:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project template: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:

[ERROR] .../src/main/java/Mapper/SourceToDestinationMap.java:[12,13] No property named "list.get(0).details.surname" exists in source parameter(s). Did you mean "list.empty"?

[ERROR] .../src/main/java/Mapper/SourceToDestinationMap.java:[11,9] No property named "list.get(0).details.forename" exists in source parameter(s). Did you mean "list.empty"?

EDIT: Current state of the mapper:

```
@Mapper
public interface SourceToDestinationMap {

    @Mapping(target = "details", source = "list")
    DestinationObject toDestination(SourceObject source);

    default DetailsObject map(List<ListObject> source) {
        return map(source.get(0));
    }

    DetailsObject map(ListObject source);
}
```

Comment: please provide the complete mapper code and the compilation errors you receive

Comment: Your mapping code is wrong, or more specifically the code for your classes is not consistent with what you are trying to map.

Comment: Sorry, I was hoping I would find someone who would just point me in the direction of how to get from an arraylist easily, expecting it to be a common task. Rather than trying to take all of the details out of my project I have created a simple project that shows what I am trying to do and I have updated my first post to reflect this. Hopefully that helps :)

Comment: Well we can't point you in the direction when we don't know what the actual problem is. It is especially difficult if your examples are not even producing a valid MapStruct code. A good place to find solutions is always the [reference documentation](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/) and the [examples](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples) repository

Answer (score 10):

The mapping you are trying to do is not possible, since you are mixing bean properties and bean functions.

You can't use `@Mapping(source = "list.get(0).XXX")`. Using indexes to access elements of a list is not yet supported see [#1321](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1321).

A way to solve your problem would be to use Qualifiers in the same way that they are used in the [mapstruct-iterable-to-non-iterable](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-iterable-to-non-iterable) example.

Or you can provide your own method that would perform the mapping.

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "details", source = "list")
    DestinationObject toDestination(SourceObject source);

    default DetailsObject map(List<ListObject> source) {
        return source != null && !source.isEmpty() ? map(source.get(0)) : null;
    }

    DetailsObject map(ListObject source);
}
```

MapStruct will then generate the correct code.

Another alternative would be to use `@Mapping(expression="java()"`.

Your mapper will then look like:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "details.forename", expression = "java(source.list.get(0).details.forename)")
    @Mapping(target = "details.surname", expression = "java(source.list.get(0).details.surname)")
    DestinationObject toDestination(SourceObject source);
}
```

Note for `expression`. MapStruct will use the text from the expression as is, and won't perform any validation checks. Therefore it can be a bit brittle, as there won't be `null` and empty checks.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! Providing my own method seems the best way to do it then. I'm having problem with the line
    return source != null && !source.isEmpty() : map(source.get(0)) : null;
As the : throw up syntax errors. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: There was a syntax error. The `:` should be `?`. You can also implement the method as you see fit. This is just an example

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't come across ternary expressions in Java before. In order to keep my code simple, I'm just going to use return map(source.get(0)); for now, as I can add validation later. I now get it compiled but the tests fail as they get null stored in the dest.details.forename variable after mapping rather than the expected tmpForename, and the same for the surname variable.

Comment: The expression way works if I change 'object' to 'objectClass' in the mapper, but I would rather do it with validation if I can.

Comment: I don't think I follow your problem. You can use my first option. Also if this satisfied your question, you should accept the answer