# Mapping nested list object with Mapstruct and MyBatis

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, mapstruct

I am not sure how to map a nested resultset into the domain entity.

Below is an bare idea on what I am trying to do:

**2 tables**

```
------------
BOOKS
------------
STUDENT_ID
BOOK_NAME
DUE_DATE

------------
STUDENTS
------------
STUDENT_ID
STUDENT_NAME
```

**DomainEntity**
(It contains the nested list)

LoanEntity.java

```
String studentId;
String studentName;
List<Book> books;
```

Book.java

```
String studentId;
String bookName;
Date dueDate;
```

**PersistenceEntity**

Loans.java

```
String studentId;
String studentName;
String bookName;
Date dueDate;
```

**Dao.xml** (Not sure how to map it, tried using [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47600244/4058682))

```
<resultMap id="loanMap" type="com.persistence.entity.Loans">
    <id property="studentId" column="studentId"/>
    <result property="studentName" column="studentName"/>
    <result property="bookName" column="bookName"/>
    <result property="dueDate" column="dueDate"/>

...
```

Note this query will duplicate the record for the # of books found.

```
SELECT
    s.STUDENT_ID, s.STUDENT_NAME, b.BOOK_NAME, b.DUE_DATE
FROM STUDENTS s
LEFT JOIN
    BOOKS b ON s.STUDENT_ID=b.STUDENT_ID
```

**LoanMapper.java**

```
@Mappings({
    @Mapping(source="studentId", target="studentId"),
    @Mapping(source="studentName", target="studentName"),
    @Mapping(source="bookName", target="books.bookName"),
    @Mapping(source="dueDate", target="books.dueDate")
})
LoanEntity persistenceToDomainEntity(Loans loans);

List<LoanEntity> persistenceToDomainEntity(List<Loans> loans);
```

Below error is what i get :

error: Unknown property "books.bookName" in result type com.loan.domain.model.Loan. Did you mean "books.empty"?
error: Unknown property "books.dueDate" in result type com.loan.domain.model.Loan. Did you mean "books.empty"?

Comment: Would the solution with plain mybatis mapping (without mapstruct) work for you? 'm not very familiar with mapstruct but it seems that you can't map the list of `Loans` into one `LoanEntity` unless you create the custom method for that (which would make mapstruct useless as you can invoke that method directly, that is no need to put it into mapstruct generated mapper).

Answer (score 0):

`books` is plural. So there's a `Collection`. MapStruct can't do things like `books.bookname` out of the box in nested mappings (these typically contain a `.`). The reason in this case is simple. You try to map something which is in a list to a singular object `bookName`. How should MapStruct know which object in the list it should pick? Which code do you expect it to generate?

So, to solve this: you can let MapStruct do the bulk of the work (I imagine you have loads of more properties than `studentId` and `studentName`.. Then you can write an additional hand written method like this:

```
@AfterMapping
default void persistenceToDomainEntity(Loans loans, @MappingTarget LoanEntity loanEntity) {
   loanEntity.setBookName( loans.getBooks().get(0).getBookName() ); //?
   loanEntity.setDueDate( loans.getBooks().get(0).getDueDate() ); //?
}

@Mappings({
    @Mapping(source="studentId", target="studentId"),
    @Mapping(source="studentName", target="studentName"),
    @Mapping(source="bookName", ignore = true),
    @Mapping(source="dueDate", ignore = true)
})
LoanEntity persistenceToDomainEntity(Loans loans);
```

That is: assuming you need the first result.

But perhaps there are even better solutions for integrating with DB's. Checkout the examples on the [MapStruct repo](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples). The one on JPA uses context to interact with the DB.